# Plot and "meaning" of the function $ f(t, e^{At}\cdot x) = \left(1-\frac{1}{c\cdot r}\ \mathrm{dist}(x,B_r(0) ) \right)^+$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, functions, graphing-functions

Fix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}, c>0, r>0.$ Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \times  \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ such that,  for all $x \in B_r(0)$, it holds that $$f(t, e^{At}\cdot x) = \left(1-\frac{1}{c \ \  r}\  \mathrm{dist}(x,B_r(0)) \right)^+.$$

1) What does this function look like when plotted, for example, with $m=2$?

2) What does it represent?

Notation: $B_r(0)$ is the ball with center $0$ and radius $r$, and $\mathrm{dist}(x,B_r(0))$ denotes the distance from $x$ to $B_r(0)$.

Comment: What is $B_r(0)$ and what is $\text{dist}(x,B_r(0))$?

Comment: @zoli: $B_r(0)$ is the ball of center $0$ and radius $r$ and $\mathrm{dist}(x,B_r(0))$ denotes the distance from $x$ to $B_r(0)$.

Comment: What does it mean to have the function defined as $f(t, e^{At} x)$? Usually when a function takes two independent inputs, it is of the form $f(t, x)$. Also, is the codomain of the function $\mathbb{R}^m$, or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Joppy I edited a typo. Actually, I'm interested in having the second variable taken in that form.

Comment: @Riku is this the same as plotting $g(t, x) = f(t, e^{-At} x)$ then?

Comment: @Joppy yes it is.

Comment: One question I have is "Is this function even well defined?" Since the second variable may have many different representatives, it's unclear that by using two different expressions of the form $e^{At}\cdot x,e^{At'}\cdot x'$ which are equal, you get the same result. Another thing is that the function as it is currently written is apparently independent of $t$?